# Laravel Eloquent Relationship - not fetching based on condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I wanted to fetch all `id` & `name` from `User` table which satisfies the condition , `order_userId` of `Orders` table == `id` of `User` table and `order` & `uploadId` columns of `Orders` table has the values `false` & `null` respectively. The below code returns all rows if data from `User` table without checking the where condition i've specified.. How can i fix this?

```
$data = User::with(['orders'=>function ($query){
            $query->where('order', false);
            $query->whereNull('uploadId');
        }])->pluck('name', 'id');
```

**User Model**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Orders::class, 'order_userId', 'id');
}
```

The above code gives an output as below:

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "jen",
        "orders": null
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "jos",
        "orders": null
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$data = User::whereHas('orders', function ($query) {
    $query->where('order', false);
    $query->whereNull('uploadId');
})->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

**try This Solution:**

The right relation is that, **User** has many **orders**.

**User Model:**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Orders::class, 'order_userId', 'id');
}
```

Comment: i tried this. Still it returns all rows of datas that even don't satisfy the where condition i specified on orders relation. Means, i wanted to get only the rows of users table that satisfy the condition `order` = `false` & `uploadId`=`null`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this also..

```
$data = User::whereHas('orders', function ($query) {
    $query->where([['order', false],['uploadId','>',0]]);
})->pluck('name', 'id');
```